# Why app data isn't on sd card even if android says its on sd card?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, sony-xperia

[image: Data on SD Card 2GB] [image: SD Card is almost empty]
"Data on SD Card 2GB" / SD Card is almost empty

Can I do something with this without rooting phone? It's same for other apps with app data.

Answer (score 0):

Apps might be movable w/o root to SD card without root but data can't, you can do that by using apps like [link2sd](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) (need root) or using android 6+ feature [adoptable storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)
You are probably wonder why is there section 'Data on SD card'. That's because data is on SD card but internal one, so it's on /sdcard partition instead of /data, but that doesn't give you any more space in internal storage.

Comment: Apps might be movable w/o root (see our [app2sd tat-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info)) – but app data cannot. So you're correct with what OP wants is impossible w/o root, but might want to update your answer nevertheless :)

Comment: Yeah, but most of time when they want to move app to SD the app data is thing that is large and part they must move to get more space on internal storage, that's why I didn't mention it. Also to move app to sd many conditions that must be met so wery few apps that requirements.